# How can I change LaunchConfig settings with Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an AutoScale and a LaunchConfig that I created earlier. I want to replace AMI ID with Cloudformation in LaunchConfig. How can I do that ?

I wonder if there is any sample template that will be a reference for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example you can find : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#aws-properties-as-launchconfig--examples

```
   ---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Description: Region specific image from the Parameter Store
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'
  InstanceType:
    Description: Amazon EC2 instance type for the instances
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - t3.micro
      - t3.small
      - t3.medium
    Default: t3.micro
Resources:
  myLaunchConfig: 
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
      SecurityGroups: 
        - Ref: "myEC2SecurityGroup"
      InstanceType: 
        Ref: "InstanceType"
      BlockDeviceMappings: 
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs: 
            VolumeSize: 30
            VolumeType: "gp3"
        - DeviceName: /dev/sdm
          Ebs: 
            VolumeSize: 100
            DeleteOnTermination: "false"
```

Comment: I already have an existing template. I just want to change the AMI id in the Launch Config inside this created Stack. I want to do this with Cloudformation too.

Comment: is it possible to put template or part of template here/in question?